# Quadratic curves of integers $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_l^{k_l}$ with $p_{i}$ $1\mod 3$ prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Consider integers of the form $$n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_l^{k_l},$$ with $p_{i}$ primes which equal $1\mod 3$.
With help of Mathematica, it seems that there exist quadratic families of subsets of values of $n$.
For example, a family of values of $n$ is given by $$n_m=1+12m^2,$$ which in particular contains $13$, $49$, etc, which are of the form stated above.
I have been able to find a number of other families of quadratic curves $n^{(i)}_m$.

My question is the following: do all $n$ of the above stated form lie on some quadratic curve? And is there a general formula which combines all such curves in a single expression?

Comment: Such numbers are exactly characterized by being of the form $a^2 + 3 b^2$ where exactly one of $a$ and $b$ are even. Any such number also lives on the quadratic (in the variable $m$) $a^2 + 3 (b + mab)^2$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Do I understand correctly that, apart from the even/odd constraint, a and b can arbitrary and as such cover all n?

Comment: when $a=3$ and $b=2$, one finds $21$. But this is not an integer of the form I am interested in. In particular, I want to exclude those pairs of $(a,b)$  such that $a^2+3b^2=0\mod 3$. Is there an easy restriction on the pairs $(a,b)$ such that this is achieved?

Comment: The first comment was correct up to powers of the special prime $3$. This is easily fixed by replacing $a$ by $3a\pm 1$ to get $(3a\pm1)^2 + 3 b^2$.